# What is the easiest way to admin a server with multiple nodes?

Tags: logging

One issue as a sysadmin that I'm facing is the logs of 1 day are in 1 server, and the logs of another day are in other server. It's absolute hassle to figure out where the logs of particular day went into. I've heard in presentation a senior colleague telling there is elasticsearch installed for that purpose, but yet, I'm not sure how to access that nor I'm sure if that really exist(I've seen nobody to use it).

Can anyone give me ideas on how do I administrate such a real life system? It was good when servers were single node!